# Performing a binary search on a text file using Java

Tags: java, file, binary-search

I have a large text file about 1 million words. I am doing this for an android phone game, and I am just trying to see if a word exists in the text file. Loading anything into memory isn't an option. The android phone memory and processor is so weak, that reading this file takes about 20 seconds.

I have modified this text file with the words, to be on equal width. Each word is 50 characters + 1 for newline. However, I am getting a little bit confused with how to properly implement a binary search, as I keep getting confused on how many bytes I should add for seek() to work properly.

```
public static long search(RandomAccessFile file, String target)
            throws IOException {

    file.seek(0);
    String line = file.readLine();

    if(line.equals(target))
        return 1;

    long start = 0;
    long end = file.length();
    long mid = (start + end -50)/2;

    while(start <= end)
    {
        file.seek(mid);
        line = file.readLine();
        if(line.compareTo(target) < 0)
            start = mid + 51;
        else if(line.equalsIgnoreCase(target))
            return 1;
        else
            end = mid - 51;

        mid = (start + end)/2;
    }

    if(start > end)
        return 0;

    return -1;
}
```

First time I set end I subtract 50 because the very last word has no new line. After a couple of iterations this stops working properly. I can't figure out how to properly make this work. Can anyone guide me on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using a trie?

Comment: Yes, trust me I have exhausted every single possible clever solution. Loading anything into memory is not a feasible solution. Reading just the file itself not even storing it, takes 20 seconds.

Comment: 1. First, add a hard return at the end of your file.... 2. **Remove** all that counting and replace it with a single simple counter! You only need to change `file.seek(mid*51)`. That should take care of your line synchronization problem. Any remaining problems should be due to your binary searching.

Comment: Don't implement your own binary search. Wrap file in an AbstractList and use `Collections.binarySearch()`.

Comment: I think you have to take into account your character encoding. Is it unicode is it UTF-8? Because the number of bytes per character depends on the encoding and you also have to `\n` into account

Comment: This is text you are talking about; as such you cannot reliably know the size of the file! But if you are _absolutely sure_ that your characters will all be encoded into one byte then use a `MappedByteBuffer`.

Comment: @Jongware This was the proper solution. The very first end I had to add 1 and divide it by 51, to get me the last line number. After that I removed all my manual counting except the adding and subtracting 1 to middle. Then I just did seek(mid*51);

Comment: If the data is too big for your memory, you can use a database (SQLite).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By wrapping file in an AbstractList, you can leverage out of box binary search implementation:

```
final int size = (int) ((file.length() + LINE_BREAK_LEN) / (WORD_LEN + LINE_BREAK_LEN));
return Collections.binarySearch(
    new AbstractList<String>() {
        public String get(int pIdx) {
            try {
                file.seek((WORD_LEN + LINE_BREAK_LEN) * pIdx);
                return file.readLine();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        }

        public int size() {return size;}
    },
    target,
    Comparator.comparing(String::toLowerCase)
);
```

Note that line breaks just complicate the code and could be omitted from file.

Comment: Very good point on the line breaks! OP can always read `WORD_LEN` characters, and remove a million bytes from the word list.

Answer (score 2):

Waite's answer is good, but it's missing an implementation of the marker interface `RandomAccess`.
Without it, `Collections.binarySearch` defaults to performing a sequential `O(n)` search, which you most definitely do not want.

Unfortunately Java doesn't seem to allow anonymous classes to both extend and implement(or implement more than 1 thing), so you'd need to use a slightly more verbose alternative:

```java
  public static long search(RandomAccessFile file, String target) throws IOException {

    final int size = (int) ((file.length() + LINE_BREAK_LEN) / (WORD_LEN + LINE_BREAK_LEN));

    class FileAsList extends AbstractList<String> implements RandomAccess {
      @Override
      public String get(int pIdx) {
        try {
          file.seek((WORD_LEN + LINE_BREAK_LEN) * pIdx);
          return file.readLine();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
          throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
      }

      @Override
      public int size() {
        return size;
      }
    }

    var list = new FileAsList();
    return Collections.binarySearch(list, target, Comparator.comparing(String::toLowerCase));
  }
```